# Angular JS module not loading in IE 9

Tags: angularjs, html, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to make a one page web app using `angular.js`

Its working absolutely fine in chrome and safari.

But its giving me error in **IE 9**.

my `ng-app` value is `modules`  and I am getting below error in IE:

> modules is undefined

Please help.

**Code**

```
<html ng-app="mainApp"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8"/> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" /> 
        <meta name="description" content="One MDM Application"/> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="allJsInclude.js">
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body ng-controller="mainAppCtrl" data-role='MainMenuDragArea' ng-class="{touchDevice: config.touchDevice, desktopStyle: !config.touchDevice}">
    </body> 
</html>

var mainAppModule = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute',
     'breadcrumbs', 'slices', 'modules', 'tableview', 'tableSettings', 'pagination',
     'ui', 'prompt']).config(function($routeProvider) { appRoutes.init($routeProvider); });
angular.module('modules', []);
```

Comment: can we see some code

Comment: here is my html...
<html ng-app="mainApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        
        <meta name="description" content="One MDM Application"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="allJsInclude.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="mainAppCtrl" data-role='MainMenuDragArea' ng-class="{touchDevice: config.touchDevice, desktopStyle: !config.touchDevice}">
    </body>

</html>

Comment: i am creating my module like this:

var mainAppModule = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute', 'breadcrumbs', 'slices', 'modules', 'tableview', 'tableSettings', 'pagination', 'ui', 'prompt'])
        .config(function($routeProvider) {
            appRoutes.init($routeProvider);
        });

angular.module('modules', []);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work in any browser? Not sure why you have created another module called modules.. but change your script to the following and you should avoid errors.

```
var mainAppModule = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute',
 'breadcrumbs', 'slices', 'modules', 'tableview', 'tableSettings', 'pagination',
 'ui', 'prompt']).config(function($routeProvider) { appRoutes.init($routeProvider);

mainAppModule.controller("mainAppCtrl", ['$scope',  function($scope){
        //put your controller functionality in here
    }
]);
```